# SQL Server trigger not working while inserting values

Tags: sql-server-2008, triggers, insert

Is it possible the insert trigger is not run while the values are inserted on the table? Anybody was experience this?

Comment: **NOPE** - triggers **will be run** - maybe your code isn't able to handle the multiple rows in `Inserted` - but the trigger **will be fired** - look for the problem in **your code** - not in SQL Server's triggering mechanism ...

Comment: I wouldn't say.. "it's not possible" but your code definitely is the more (much more) likely culprit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it's not possible, if you have the trigger set up correctly. Are you sure you've indicated you want the trigger to fire on an Insert? You have the option of specifying a trigger to fire on an Insert, Update, Delete or any combination.

Or the trigger could be disabled. Or there could be a Return statement in the first line of the trigger. I've seen people do that, as a way to disable a trigger.

Also, if you are inserting multiple rows into the table, you need to make sure your trigger is created correctly to handle that. Handling multiple inserts can be a bit more complicated than handling a single insert, and unexpected results could occur if you are not aware of the difference.